# Subscribe method to arbitrary event

Tags: c#, events, reflection

In C#, I'd like to use Reflection to subscribe a method to an event with an arbitrary signature. Consider the following code:

```
void Subscribe(object objectWithEvent, string eventName) {
    EventInfo eventInfo = objectWithEvent.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);
    MethodInfo addMethod = eventInfo.GetAddMethod();
    MethodInfo MethodToInvoke = this.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod");
    Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, MethodToInvoke);
    addMethod.Invoke(objectWithEvent, new object[1]{ d });
}
```

This code successfully subscribes `MyMethod` to `objectWithEvent.EventName`, but *only* if the event matches the signature of `MyMethod` exactly. I'd like to be able to subscribe `MyMethod` to any event, perhaps by declaring `MyMethod` like so:

```
public void MyMethod(params object[] parameters)
```

Simply doing this didn't work, however.

There's also the return type to worry about. Most event handlers return `void`, so the ability to handle events which return other than `void` isn't strictly required (though it would be nice).

How can I use reflection, if possible, to subscribe to an event with an arbitrary signature?

Comment: You should make `MethodToInvoke` a parameter of `Subscribe` rather than a property.

Comment: The problem, Dai, is that I'd like to be able to subscribe *the same* method to *any* event, which is why I don't want it to be a parameter. I would *always* like to subscribe `MyMethod`, I just want to subscribe it to arbitrary events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Reflection to create and compile DynamicMethod matching signature of `EventHandlerType` containing the invocation of your `public object MyMethod(params object[] parameters)`. There will be some conditional code for the return type, if needed.

More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(v=vs.110).aspx